# Reorder list, pull 3 values from around the middle and put at the end

Tags: python

Here is my list cols:

```
cols
Out[11]: 
['ga:date',
 'ga:hour',
 'ga:dimension1',
 'ga:dimension2',
 'ga:userType',
 'ga:landingpagePath',
 'ga:deviceCategory',
 'ga:sessions',
 'ga:goal1Completions',
 'ga:bounces',
 'ga:operatingSystem',
 'ga:source',
 'ga:medium',
 'ga:campaign',
 'ga:adContent',
 'ga:keyword']
```

I wouldlike to reorder it so that ga:sessions, ga:bounces and ga:goal1Completions are at the end.

Rather than type it manually, how can I first remove those items from the middle of cols and then append them at the end?

Desired result:

```
cols
Out[11]: 
['ga:date',
 'ga:hour',
 'ga:dimension1',
 'ga:dimension2',
 'ga:userType',
 'ga:landingpagePath',
 'ga:deviceCategory',
 'ga:operatingSystem',
 'ga:source',
 'ga:medium',
 'ga:campaign',
 'ga:adContent',
 'ga:keyword',
 'ga:sessions',
 'ga:goal1Completions',
 'ga:bounces']
```

Comment: Do you know indexes before? If so then `l = l[:7] + l[10:] + l[7:10]`

Comment: Ah, thank you. I wondered if there's a way to order the list based on the value as opposed to indexes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
l = sorted(l, key=lambda v: 1 if v in ('ga:goal1Completions', 'ga:bounces', 'ga:operatingSystem') else 0)
print(l)
```

Prints:

```
['ga:date', 'ga:hour', 'ga:dimension1', 'ga:dimension2', 'ga:userType', 'ga:landingpagePath', 'ga:deviceCategory', 'ga:sessions', 'ga:source', 'ga:medium', 'ga:campaign', 'ga:adContent', 'ga:keyword', 'ga:goal1Completions', 'ga:bounces', 'ga:operatingSystem']
```

Or with weights, if you want **exactly** the group in the order:

```
weights = {'ga:sessions':1, 'ga:goal1Completions':2, 'ga:bounces':3}
l = sorted(l, key=lambda v: 0 if v not in weights else weights[v])
print(l)
```

Output:

```
['ga:date', 'ga:hour', 'ga:dimension1', 'ga:dimension2', 'ga:userType', 'ga:landingpagePath', 'ga:deviceCategory', 'ga:operatingSystem', 'ga:source', 'ga:medium', 'ga:campaign', 'ga:adContent', 'ga:keyword', 'ga:sessions', 'ga:goal1Completions', 'ga:bounces']
```